# Is this a presentation of a known group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

I am trying to determine whether $$\langle x, y\mid xyxy=1\rangle$$ is homomorphic to a known group. I cannot decide on a possible canditate from the groups I know and I cant seem to find this group on any list. Could someone help me me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $z = xy$. Note that $$\langle x, y : xyxy = 1\rangle = \langle x, z : z^2 = 1 \rangle$$ so your group is isomorphic to the free product $$ \mathbf Z \ast \mathbf Z/ 2\mathbf Z.$$